# Grizzly/Jersey: Generate keystore from certificates

Tags: java, jersey, certificate, ssl-certificate, grizzly

I have th following certificate files:

- private.pem (RSA PRIVATE KEY)
- request.pem (CERTIFICATE REQUEST)
- cert.pem (Signed CERTIFICATE from the CA, based on the request.pem)
- chain.txt (The corresonding certificate chain)

In my apache, I use the files as follows:

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/private.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.txt
```

This works well. Now I want to use the same certificates within my SSL enabled Grizzly server.

How do I create a valid `keystore` file from the files?

The following commands are not enougth:

```
keytool -import -alias serverKey -file cert.pem -keystore ./keystore
keytool -import -alias caChain -file chain.txt -keystore ./keystore
```

For testsing issues I am using the `keystore_server` from the [jersey-svn](https://svn.java.net/svn/jersey~svn/trunk/jersey/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly/), which works well (with the well known certificate warnings), while my generated `keystore` file does not work. What do I miss?

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found a working solution: http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html